# Missing Edges - How can i fix this?

Tags: vertices, edges

im new to blender and Im following a tutorial.
Yesterday, i was working on vertices and edges to create a 'human face'. i saved it.
Today, i opened my file again and i realise that some of the edges(i used subdivide) are missing.
i tried to subdivide but its reading as if its a second subdivide and not on the supposed curved edge.[image]

is it still posible to fix this??

Comment: Does it still happen when you de-select that little blue, upside down triangle shape in the sub-division surface modifier you have there?

Comment: @MarkGrant I de-select the 'On Cage' and still not reveal those edge

Comment: I would have said as Mark Grant, but please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots i tried uploading it https://pasteall.org/blend/dde90c39ed924b38abe517f0419c27e7

Comment: so that's what Mark said, the Subdivision Surface modifier creates new vertices, you can't select them as they are virtual (you need to apply the modifier to make them exist).

Comment: @moonboots i see.. i understand it now :)